# JavaScript all images loading before await

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a simple JavaScript file that gets multiple image files from a local device and displays a thumb of the images. So far so good.

Once the thumbs are displayed I have a button that calls the addImages() function. I need to display a slide show of the images, one at a time, for 3 seconds. However, what is happening is all the images are showing at the same time, then the sleep function is called, and then remove the image. Here is my code:

```
        function addImages() {
    var preview = document.querySelector('#display');
                
        async function readAndPreview(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
        
                reader.addEventListener("load", async function () {
                    var image = new Image();
                    image.height = 400;
                    image.width = 400;
                    image.title = file.name;
                    image.border = 5;
                    image.src = this.result;
                    preview.appendChild(image);
                    sleep(3000).then(()=> preview.removeChild(image))


                }, false);
        
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }   

    if(files) {
            [].forEach.call(files, readAndPreview);
    }
    }

  function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }
```

It looks like the code iterates through to appendChild and then starts again until all images are added and then calls the sleep functions and then removeChild. Why???

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure `addEventListener` will do anything with that async callback, except call it maybe?

Comment: `.forEach()` doesn't care about `async` callbacks or an `await` in its callback (nor about an `await` in a callback in its callback)

Comment: can you recommend a change in the code?

Comment: try and change this `await sleep(3000)` to `sleep(3000).then(()=> preview.removeChild(image))`.

Comment: thanks @kunal panchal however same problem. all the images load before the sleep. I need Image1 then sleep, then image2 then sleep etc...

Comment: I don't think async/await syntax can properly convert callbacks to promises. Try using the promise constructor like in the sleep function?

Comment: I think the problem is an understanding of the event loop of javascript, if I understand your project the onload fonction is trigered each time their is an onload: promise is not working like usual code: javascript have an order and I think it will do all appened child image then it will do mitliple sleep; you should do the sleep methode with a .then() and un it do the ```append.child(img)```

Comment: Ok I have edit my code but I still have the same problem. All images are loaded before the sleep function is called and then all images are removed after  3sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed a lot of the implementation as proposed by you.

Major changes:-

1. Having one instance of file reader
2. Having single image for which we keep on changing the src url after designated time. (Came to this conclusion after I saw that you're trying to append and remove the same image element after certain duration). So yes I am assuming that the focus will always be one image at a time and so the below code.

```
let files // you must have an array initialized I think
let reader;
const preview = document.querySelector('#display');
let image = new Image();
image.height = 400;
image.width = 400;
image.title = file.name;
image.border = 5;
preview.appendChild(image);

function initReader(){
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
          image.src = this.result;   
         }, false);   
}

 function addImages() { 
        initReader();        
        async function readAndPreview() {
                for (let index = 0;index<files.length;index++){
                reader.readAsDataURL(files[index]);
                await sleep(3000);
         } 
        }   
        readAndPreview();      
    }

  function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }
```

I haven't run this so there might be scope of mistakes. But this approach should work for your use-case.

Also there is scope of improvement in this approach for smooth transition from one image to another. Usually one can preload all images via blobs [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) and store them in an array over which we loop and update the image `src` as we did above. Will be much faster since the data is already at client side.